# SUMIF condition following a specific letter

Tags: excel, range, conditional-statements, sumifs

I am trying to build in a condition in a `SUMIF` formula where it checks that after the letter u that the next letter is a number. I tried `ISNUMBER`, putting in a condition to check that it is a larger then 1, or a number from 1-9.

I need to expand this formula

```
=SUMIF(sheety!$A1:$A, 'sheetx'$C338&"u"&[get it it to check that the
 first one after is a number], sheety)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checking for a number 1 character immediately after "u" to work like this, where the string to search is in cell B1, and the formula goes into cell A1:

```
="'sheetx"&"u"&IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B1,1+SEARCH("u",B1),1))),
VALUE(MID(B1,1+SEARCH("u",B1),1)),"")&"!"
```

I am not sure I understand exactly where this string is, that you wish to search (I assume it is some other cell).

If you provide a screen shot, or more detailed example of what the `SUMIF` is actually summing and how you are expecting the criteria to work, I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a ? for a single character like this

`=SUMIF(sheety!$A:$A,'sheetx'!$C338&"u?",sheety!$B:$B)`

That won't check for an actual number, but unless you also have values with letters following the "u" it should work OK. Note: I'm assuming that there will be nothing after that number, if there is then add another wildcard, this time *

For explicitly checking for numbers try like this:

`=SUM(SUMIF(sheety!$A:$A,'sheetx'!$C338&"u"&{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},sheety!$B:$B))`

Answer (score 0):

This formula may not meet your exact requirements, but it may help you get on the right path.

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2:A5,FIND("u",A2:A5)+1,1)))=TRUE,VALUE(MID(A2:A5,FIND("u",A2:A5)+1,1))))}
```

Curly brackets because you must press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`, instead of just `Enter`.

Let's break it down

Here's the data

```
    Col A
1   data
2   xux
3   xu1
4   u9
5   u5
```

First we need to find out where "u" is in the string:

```
{=FIND("u",A2:A5)}
```

This will return the array: `2,2,1,1`

Then we expand it to return the character after "u" (based on the location of the first "u" and assuming that the number is just 1 character)

```
{=MID(A2,
         FIND("u",A2)
  +1,1)}
```

This will return the array: `x,1,9,5`

Then we can expand to test to see if it's a number

```
{=ISNUMBER(
           VALUE(
                 MID(A2,FIND("u",A2)+1,1)
                 )
           )}
```

This will return the array: `FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE`

Now we can sum based on a criteria.

```
 {=SUM(
       IF(
          ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2:A5,FIND("u",A2:A5)+1,1)))=TRUE
          ,VALUE(MID(A2:A5,FIND("u",A2:A5)+1,1))))}
```